# What is the graql query for getting everything in the graph

Tags: vaticle-typeql, mindmapsdb, vaticle-typedb

I have a small graph with just a couple of vertices. How can I print out all the vertices in the graph using graql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean all the instances. In that case, the easiest way is:

`match $x isa $type; $type isa concept-type; select $x`

If you only want entities, you can change `concept-type` to `entity-type` above.

Comment: is there a way to get the ontology, i.e. all the types? I defined a resource type and an entity type.

Comment: That would be `match $x isa concept-type`. This works because `resource-type` and `entity-type` are both subtypes of `concept-type`.

Answer (score 2):

```
match $a isa $b
```

This gives you everything in the graph, because everything has a type.